# Flex: Convert ArrayCollection to jagged String Array

Tags: asp.net, apache-flex, jagged-arrays

Is there any built in functionality to convert an ArrayCollection to a jagged string array? I have an Arraycollection of objectproxies that I get from a SOAP webservice (asp.net datatable) that I modify and want to send back.

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Not that I know of, you might have to code it yourself. Shouldn't be too difficult though the testing might be tedious.

Comment: This ight be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099731/initialize-a-jagged-array-the-linq-way

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up writing something myself to do it. I was just hoping that there was another way.