# Initialize double[][][] as double[1][2][3] using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Can we initialize an array of double[][][] as double[1][2][3] (this is not the correct syntax) using linq.

using for loop one way is

```
double[][][] myarr = new double[1][][];
for(int i=0; i<1; i++)
{
    myarr[i] = new double[2][];
    for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
    {
         myarr[i][j] = new double[3];
    }
}
```

but i want a cleaner code. I tried Select but it only fills first level. How to go about it. Thanks

& btw this is not homework!!

Comment: Could you show your code for that select?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099731/initialize-a-jagged-array-the-linq-way OR http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738990/initializing-multidimensional-jagged-arrays

Comment: I think the code you already have is most readable

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using a multidimensional array? Like `double[, ,] myarr = new double[1, 2, 3];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
double[][][] threeDimensionArray = 
  Enumerable.Range(0, 1)
            .Select(h1 => Enumerable.Range(0, 2)
                                    .Select(h2 => new double[3])
                                    .ToArray())
            .ToArray();
```

But this requires multiple `ToArray()` calls which doing memory copy (see implementaiton below) so for big number of items it would not be efficient so such kind of "elegant" solution is not for free. BTW, I would prefer `for` loop solution.

`Enumerable.ToArray()` implementation: (credits to [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx))

```
// System.Linq.Enumerable
public static TSource[] ToArray<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }

     // sll: see implementation of Buffer.ToArray() below
    return new Buffer<TSource>(source).ToArray();
}

// System.Linq.Buffer<TElement>
internal TElement[] ToArray()
{
    if (this.count == 0)
    {
        return new TElement[0];
    }
    if (this.items.Length == this.count)
    {
        return this.items;
    }
    TElement[] array = new TElement[this.count];
    Array.Copy(this.items, 0, array, 0, this.count);
    return array;
}
```