# Initializing Jagged Array with the same non-default value

Tags: c#, linq, jagged-arrays

I am trying to create a jagged array of 10 by 10 using Linq and I want to populate it (for now) all with the same letter (not character). However, I am having trouble figuring out how to populate it in the same Linq statement.

I currently have (similar to [Initialize a Jagged Array the LINQ Way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1099731/initialize-a-jagged-array-the-linq-way)):

```
public static string[][] computerBoard = new string[10][]
    .Select(x => new string[10])
    .ToArray();
```

But that creates array of `null` strings. How to modify it to set all elements to the same value as `"A"`? Or should I use a double for loop to populate it?

I have tried doing this:

```
public static string[][] computerBoard = new string[10][]
    .Select(x => new string[10]
    .Select(y => y = "/*my letter*/"))
    .ToArray();
```

but it gives me an error:

> CS0226: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Ienumerable[]' to 'string[][]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Aren't you missing a `ToArray()`? I dont have a VS around, but something similar to `(y => y = "/*my letter*/").ToArray()).ToArray()`

Comment: A 10 by 10 array of arrays is not "jagged".

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Semantics. It's of a structure known as a jagged array, as opposed to a multidimensional array. In theory, subsequent logic could change the contents of the outer array to have arrays with more or fewer elements in them.

Comment: @Cleptus was right, I was missing .ToArray()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're going for:

```
public static string[][] computerBoard = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .Select(x => Enumerable.Repeat("/*my letter*/", 10).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I like your usage of `Enumerable.Repeat` better than my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ really isn't the right tool for this, it's used to iterate over existing collections. Think of it like a fancier foreach loop.

That being said, by usage of `Enumerable.Range` you can get what you want.

```
string[][] foo = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
    .Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
        .Select(j => "a")
        .ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

This will give you a 10x10 array filled with nothing but the letter "a".

Additionally I'll note, that not only is LINQ generally the wrong tool for this, it also isn't very readable.